# The program 'gsi' is currently not installed. Gambit Scheme

Tags: software-installation

I installed the Gambit Scheme with the source from [here](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/download/gambit/v4.6/source/) as follows:

```
cd gambcfolder...
./configure --enable-single-host
make
sudo make install
```

But something is wrong. When I run `gsi` I get an error:

```
The program 'gsi' is currently not installed. 
You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install gambc
```

I had installed gambc from the repository, but I had some problems using SLIB, so I removed it.

Comment: can you do `sudo updatedb` , `locate gsi` and `locate gambit` and post output

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/gz25ANC9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove old link in the `/usr/bin`

```
 sudo rm /usr/bin/gsi
```

Make new Link

```
 ln -s ~/Downloads/gambc-v4_6_0/gsi/gsi /usr/bin/gsi
```

And enjoy

Comment: I tried it: bash: /usr/bin/gsi: No such file or directory

Comment: did you do `sudo updatdb` before `locate gsi` and `locate gambit` in http://pastebin.com/gz25ANC9 ?

Comment: Yes, I did. What can I do?

Comment: can you do `cd /usr/bin` and `ls | grep "gsi"` and check if gsi is infact there

Comment: This returned the gsi name in red.

Comment: enter `gsi` in terminal then and post the error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14077/discussion-between-back-slash-and-dxhj)